# x3d - transparent texture with different repeat level

Tags: opacity, multitexturing, x3d

I want to create a terrain layer using a repeated base texture using a non-repeated opacity map. (either in alpha or as separate texture)

```
<Appearance>
    <MultiTexture mode='"MODULATE" "MODULATE"'>
        <ImageTexture repeatS="true" repeatT="true" url='"textures/terrain_pavement.jpg"'/>
        <ImageTexture url='"textures/terrain_pavement_opacity.png"'/>

        <!--<PixelTexture image="2 2 2 
            0x0000 0xFFFF
            0xFFFF 0x0000"/>-->
    </MultiTexture>
    <MultiTextureTransform>
       <TextureTransform scale="12 4"/>
       <TextureTransform/>
    </MultiTextureTransform>
</Appearance>
```

Using a pixeltexture gives the correct result, but my opacity.png map is saved as 8bit grayscale too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not well supported using X3D itself or most players.

Using old `wrl` format it worked as expected.